# Notification email with data from different columns when edit is made to cell in the same row

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, notifications, google-apps-script-triggers

I've browsed similar questions but I'm a bit flabbergasted.

Google Sheet name: Book List Records
Tab Name: Books sent to Wisconsin

When any cell in column E is (manually) changed in the tab mentioned above, I would like an email to send to three different people. I would like the email message to mention the data in column B (Book Title) and C (Book Author) of the row where the cell was changed. i.e. "Hello admin team! Being Alive by Sandra Owen has an updated status (cell E#), changing from oldvalue to newvalue."

This is as far as I've gotten.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = e.range;
  var row = editedCell.getRow();
  var col = editedCell.getColumn();
  
  //Check if E:F was modified in Sheet "Book List Records" based on its row and column index
  if(row>=3 && row<=90 && col>=5 && col<=6 && editedSheet.getName()=="Books sent to Wisconsin"){
    //Send email
    var subject = "Change to Book List spreadsheet";
    var message = "{Cell B#} by {Cell C#} has an updated status (cell "+editedCell.getA1Notation()+"), changing from '"+e.oldvalue+"' to '"+e.value+"'";
    MailApp.sendEmail("name1@email.com,name2@email.com,name3@email.com",subject,message);
  }
}
```

How do I pull the value in columns B & C of the row where the cell was edited? ex. cell E89 was changed; I want the email to refer to the value of cell B89 and C89.

Comment: Your script looks good, just make sure you setup an [installable onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). If you not do that, it will not run because you are using MailApp.sendEmail which is not permitted in a simple trigger.

Comment: I think I've set up the onEdit trigger now. How do I pull the value in column B of the row where the cell in column E was edited?

Comment: e.range.getValue()

Comment: Hmm that pulls the value of the edited cell. How do I pull the value in columns B & C of the row where the cell was edited? ex. cell E89 was changed; I want the email to refer to the value of cell B89 and C89.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: so if I'm referring to the value in column B, I tried using e.range.getValue(row,2) which doesn't work. neither does writing row[2]

Comment: Also, "+e.oldvalue+" doesn't seem to work - the email always says "undefined" whether the original cell was blank or had existing data.

Comment: you need only e.range.getValue(). consult the apps script reference https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue